# HTML5 CSS3 modal window, close when click outside

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, modal-dialog, modal-window

I use the modal window as described by Keenan Payne, made with HTML5 & CSS3.
I would like it to close when the user clicks on the darkened background, outside the modal window. Does anybody knows how to do this?

Modal window by Keenan Payne:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the target on something different than #openModal. You can import jQuery, put this in `<head>` section:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and add this code right before `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#openModal").click( function() {
        if (!$("#openModal>div").is(":hover")) document.location.href='#';
    });
</script>
```

So when user clicks on the overlay the target will change on '#' and the modal will be closed.

Comment: did you import jQuery library properly?

Comment: Good one, probably not.
But I don't want to import to much, because I want the website to be super fast en easy to load....