# Close Modal Upon Click Outside (CSS + HTML Only)

Tags: html, css

Greetings and thank you in advance

**Summary**

- **Modal**
- **Works** like a charm (close button works fine too)
- **Need to close it when user clicks outside**
- No JS / jQuery **(CSS +  HTML only)**

**Similar posts / issues**

- [Closing Modal Popup by Clicking Away from It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439779/closing-modal-popup-by-clicking-away-from-it) *(Script based fix)*
- [Close Modal using CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230393/close-modal-using-css-only) *(Script based fix)*
- [Disable Close Modal on Outside Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908243/disable-close-modal-on-outside-click) *(Script based fix)*
- [HTML5 CSS3 modal window, close when click outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684599/html5-css3-modal-window-close-when-click-outside) *(Script based fix)*
- [Close a div by clicking outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965839/close-a-div-by-clicking-outside) *(Script based fix)*
- [Close modal window when clicking outside or ESC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000467/close-modal-window-when-clicking-outside-or-esc) *(Script based fix)*

**Example of the Effect Desired - `achived by using script`**

- [W3.CSS Modal](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal_close)

**Possible fixes**

- [Close modal by clicking outside the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302301/close-modal-by-clicking-outside-the-box) (please read the last answer at the bottom)
- [CSS/HTML Modal- Using the Escape key/Click outside to close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758991/css-html-modal-using-the-escape-key-click-outside-to-close) (please note the note attached to the first answer)

> Note, that closing modal is technically possible with CSS/HTML only...

**Question**

How can I make a **modal close** when the user **clicks outside** by using `CSS` and `HTML` only?

*My `CSS`and `HTML`are in the snippet below (Not fully resposive - open in fullscreen)*

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.content {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: trim;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto
}
.mbutton {
  border: 1px solid rgba(115, 117, 117, 0.6);
  padding: 8px 60px 8px 60px;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modal > div {
  background: rgba(115, 117, 117, 0.6);
  width: 12em;
}
.close {
  margin: 0 auto 0.7em auto;
  max-width: 15%;
}
.wrap,
.modal {
  display: flex
}
.mbutton:hover,
.close,
.mitem {
  color: #111
}
.content,
.mbutton,
.close:hover,
.mitem:hover {
  color: #999
}
.mitem,
.close {
  display: block
}
.wrap,
.modal {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}
.mbutton:hover,
.mitem {
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.9);
}
.mitem,
.modal > div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
.mitem:hover,
.modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}
.mbutton,
.modal > div {
  margin: 5% auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="#M" class="mbutton">Menu</a>
    <div id="M" class="modal">
      <div>
        <a href="#" title="Close Menu" class="close">&#9747;</a>
        <a href="http://google.com" class="mitem">Home</a>
        <a href="http://yahoo.com" class="mitem">Photos</a>
        <a href="http://bing.com" class="mitem">Details</a>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="mitem">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
      <br>
      <br>sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam
      aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi
      <br>
      <br>>qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum
      quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you open the modal? Are you doing that without javascript?

Comment: Yes, the modal opens and closes (using close button) without JavaScript

Comment: Clever method.  Fun!

Comment: @ILoveCSS didn't it work?

Comment: It works! @jafarbtech Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Another `a` inside your target with width and height match with `position:fixed;` the parent and having less `z-index` than the model content `div` which should be `position:relative`

**Change**

in html:-

```
        <a href="#" title="Close Menu" class="bodyclose"></a>
```

in css:-

```
.bodyclose {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display:none;
  z-index:1;
  position:fixed;
}
.modal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modal:target > .bodyclose {
  display:block;
}
.modal > div {
  background: rgba(115, 117, 117, 0.6);
  width: 12em;
  z-index:2;
  position:relative;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.content {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: trim;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto
}
.mbutton {
  border: 1px solid rgba(115, 117, 117, 0.6);
  padding: 8px 60px 8px 60px;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.bodyclose {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display:none;
  z-index:1;
  position:fixed;
}
.modal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modal:target > .bodyclose {
  display:block;
}
.modal > div {
  background: rgba(115, 117, 117, 0.6);
  width: 12em;
  z-index:2;
  position:relative;
}
.close {
  margin: 0 auto 0.7em auto;
  max-width: 15%;
}
.wrap,
.modal {
  display: flex
}
.mbutton:hover,
.close,
.mitem {
  color: #111
}
.content,
.mbutton,
.close:hover,
.mitem:hover {
  color: #999
}
.mitem,
.close {
  display: block
}
.wrap,
.modal {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}
.mbutton:hover,
.mitem {
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.9);
}
.mitem,
.modal > div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
.mitem:hover,
.modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}
.mbutton,
.modal > div {
  margin: 5% auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="#M" class="mbutton">Menu</a>
    <div id="M" class="modal">
      <div>
        <a href="#" title="Close Menu" class="close">&#9747;</a>
        <a href="http://google.com" class="mitem">Home</a>
        <a href="http://yahoo.com" class="mitem">Photos</a>
        <a href="http://bing.com" class="mitem">Details</a>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" class="mitem">Contact</a>
      </div>
        <a href="#" title="Close Menu" class="bodyclose"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
      <br>
      <br>sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam
      aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi
      <br>
      <br>>qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum
      quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Updated the answer. it works in across all browsers now :). thanks @cale_b

Comment: i have updated the reason for that browser issue in the description itself

Comment: Thank you very much the update @jafarbtech, unless there is some other incompatibility (checked with chrome, firefox and IE 11) It works as intend. Answer selected. Thank you for your time all!!

Comment: welcome. But this is a good method of popup. I appreciate u (y)